# What is the fastest way to export floor plans (visually)?

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, revit

I'm looking for the fastest way to export floor plans (hundreds) via revit api from a Revit model so that the output will be a visible indication of the floor plan (image, dwg, dxf, thumbnail, pdf).

Given over 400 floor plans, I've tried:

Image export with various settings, tested as low as 72dpi with 256 pixel - about 20 min
DWG export - about 17 min.
DXF export - about 17 min.

Are there any other ways to export the floor plans in a quick manner?
speed is the key in my problem as long as there is some viable output for each plan.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting benchmark results. It is not 100% clear to me whether you are referring to the native Revit API on the Windows platform or the Forge Design Automation environment. Can you please clarify?

Comment: The code is meant for Forge Design Automation. But its tested locally within windows before uploading to DA. I was thinking about multithreading but I've read (in your blog mainly) its not possible (since I will be calling the Export() function and its part of the revit api).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Yes, multi-threading cannot be used for the Revit API, unfortunately. OK, now I see. I'll ask the development team whether they have any suggestions for you.

Answer (score 0):

I took this up with the development team for you. So far, they have provided one pretty interesting suggestion:

Is it possible to open the model in multiple versions of Revit at once, say N, and have each version export one view (or 400/N views)?